# What does the "usage" mean in the "Get-PhysicalDisk" results?

Tags: windows, powershell, storage-spaces

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-usage) for `Get-PhysicalDisk` simply listed the possible options for the `Usage` parameter. Does anyone know how those values are defined?

Comment: Windows has the capability to create a RAID on software level. The different usage values  look like you can define the role of a disk in such a RAID (e.g. `HotSpare`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values are mostly for RAID members. Their meaning is
the allocation method of each physical disk, as follows:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Unknown | The intended usage is not specified. |
| Auto-Select | This physical disk should only be used for data storage. |
| Manual-Select | This physical disk should only be used if manually selected by an administrator at the time of virtual disk creation. A manual-select disk is selected using the `PhysicalDisksToUse` parameter to `CreateVirtualDisk`. |
| Hot Spare | This physical disk should be used as a hot spare. |
| Retired | This physical disk should be retired from use. At a minimum, no new allocations should go to this disk. If the virtual disks that reside on this disk are repaired, the data should be moved to another active physical disk. |
| Journal | This physical disk should be used as a cache for other devices comprising a virtual disk. It will back a virtual disk s write-back cache, if configured. |

Non-RAID disks, according to my test, are marked as Auto-Select.

Source :
[MSFT_PhysicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-physicaldisk).

Comment: wow...did not expect to dig down to the API level to learn a command parameter.